# Cinema Seats Select and Deselect not Working in JButton?

Tags: java, swing

when I execute this segment of code it displays a grid of buttons out of which only the one at the bottom corner of the grid works while others do not. When you click on a button it will turn green meaning it's selected and if you click on it again it will become white meaning deselected. I want to make a cinema theater seat booking system in which the user will select their own seat. I cant figure out why the others aren't working.

Can anyone help me out?

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import java.io.File;
    class cinemaSeats extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
    private JButton[] bt = new JButton[1]; 

    static int c=4;
    static int k=5;
      public cinemaSeats() throws IOException{ 
      this.setSize(100, 100); 


      this.setLayout(null); 
     for(int s=0;s<=10;s++,k+=30)
      {
       c=4;
         for(int j=1;j<=10;j++,c+=30)
           {
              for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++) { 
              bt[i] = new JButton(""); 
              this.add(bt[i]); 

              bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
              bt[i].addActionListener(this); 
              bt[i].setBounds(c,k,30,30);
   } 
  }
 }
    this.setVisible(true); 
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(new Dimension(3400,735));
} 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++) { 
       if (e.getSource() == bt[i]) { 
       if(bt[i].getBackground() == Color.GREEN){ 
       bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
       }else if(bt[i].getBackground() == Color.WHITE){ 
       bt[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
       }else{ 
       bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
      } 
     } 
    } 
   }
  }

    public class cinemaSeat1 { 
     public static void main()throws IOException { 
     cinemaSeats bcts = new cinemaSeats(); 
   } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bt` array has length `1`. Even though you're creating multiple `JButton` you keep a reference only to one of them (the last one created).
Because of that, when you get to `actionPerformed` the `if (e.getSource() == bt[i])` condition will be `true` only when the last button created is pressed.

You will have to keep references to all the buttons or you could do something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton pressedButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
    if(pressedButton.getBackground() == Color.GREEN){ 
       pressedButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    }else if(pressedButton.getBackground() == Color.WHITE){ 
       pressedButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
    }else{ 
       pressedButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    } 
}
```